# Find what ASP.NET MVC controller in master view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a shared master view for all my other views. It's in this master view I show the menu. Now I need to find out in what controller I'm currently in so I can disable/enable certain menu options.

For example it should be possible to press the "foo" link if I'm current in the "foo" controller.

How Can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Could you use?

```
<%=Html.ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller") %>
```

Kindness,

Dan

Answer (score 8):

[You can find it with the **viewcontext**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewcontext_members.aspx)

Comment: Think ViewContext should hold this info.